# kinect 2 JointOrientation vs kinect 1 absolute rotation

Tags: xna, kinect

I need to translate the data from kinect 2 joint orientation so it will be in same format as kinect 1 BoneOrientation.

I've tried to understand from documentation what extacly the Joint orientation quaternions represent but with no success. I've tried comparing kinect 1 and kinect 2 and it looks like kinect 2 gives absolute rotation. but starting from the limbs (hands, shoulders, legs) there is a great difference. 
When trying to use this data in my XNA avatar it looks like the shoulders and elbow are twisted.

Need some help to understand how to translate from kinect 2 to kinect 1.